# Need to encrypt PDF with AES-128 bit encryption in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, encryption

I need to be able to encrypt a PDF with AES-128 bit encryption to be opened using Adobe 7+.  Has anyone done this or found a free/cheap utility to do this?

Comment: We wound up using ASPose.PDF for .Net.  Seemed to work for us.

Answer (score 1):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) supports AES 128bit encryption. It is open source and free to use in some scenarios.
[PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/PDFsharpFeatures.ashx) also supports 128bit encryption but it does not say on their website whether they support AES or only RC4.

Comment: According the PDFSharp forums, it appears that PDFSharp only deals with RC4.

Comment: PDFSharp will not read an AES-128 bit file created with Adobe 7+.

Answer (score 1):

ABCpdf .NET supports both 256 bit AES (AESV3) as well as 128 bit (AESV2).

Not many tools support 256 bit because there is a quantum leap required between 128 and 256. It's not just a matter of increasing the key size.

My replies may feature concepts based around ABCpdf. It's what I work on. It's what I know. :-)